# Tic-Tac-Toe class and methods

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to learn python and am still a bit foggy on classes.
Am i using them right in this tic-tac-toe game? Everything function like i want it too but not sure if i am really getting how to use classes. Any other suggestion for improvement are welcome as well.

```
import random
import time
class TicTacToe(object):


    def __init__(self):
        self.draw=0
        self.grd_lst = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
        self.grd_lstr1 =[] 
        self.place = ''
        self.num_left = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        self.chk = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
        self.frst_chk = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
        self.y = 0
        self.row_1 = 0
        self.row_2 = 0
        self.row_3 = 0
        self.col_1 = 0
        self.col_2 = 0
        self.col_3 = 0
        self.dig_1 = 0
        self.dig_2 = 0
        self.plyr_win = False
        self.comp_win = False
        #self.win = [self.row_1,self.row_2,self.row_3,self.col_1,self.col_2,self.col_3,self.dig_1,self.dig_2]
    def plyr_chs(self):

        self.place = ''

        while self.place not in self.chk:
            self.place = input('choose x position\n')
            if self.place not in self.frst_chk:
                print ('not valid!!\n')
            elif self.place not in self.chk:
                print ('number already taken!!\n')


    def comp_chs(self):

        self.place = random.choice(self.chk)
        print ('Computer chose', self.place)

    def check(self):

        if self.place in self.chk:
            self.chk.remove(self.place)

        elif self.place == ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
            time.sleep(2)
            print ('That number is already taken. Try another number.')
        else:
            time.sleep(2)
            print ('That is not a valid entry')



    def winner(self,y):
        self.y = int(y)

        if self.place == '1':
            self.row_1 += y
            self.col_1 += y
            self.dig_1 += y

        elif self.place == '2':
            self.row_1 += y
            self.col_2 += y

        elif self.place == '3':
            self.row_1 += y
            self.col_3 += y
            self.dig_2 += y

        elif self.place == '4':
            self.row_2 += y
            self.col_1 += y

        elif self.place == '5':
            self.row_2 += y
            self.col_2 += y
            self.dig_1 += y
            self.dig_2 += y

        elif self.place == '6':
            self.row_2 += y
            self.col_3 += y

        elif self.place == '7':
            self.row_3 += y
            self.col_1 += y
            self.dig_2 += y

        elif self.place == '8':
            self.row_3 += y
            self.col_2 += y

        elif self.place == '9':
            self.row_3 += y
            self.col_3 += y
            self.dig_1 += y
        if 3 in (self.row_1,self.row_2,self.row_3,self.col_1,self.col_2,self.col_3,self.dig_1,self.dig_2):
            self.plyr_win = True
            print('You won!!!')

        elif -3 in (self.row_1,self.row_2,self.row_3,self.col_1,self.col_2,self.col_3,self.dig_1,self.dig_2):
            self.comp_win = True
            print('You lost... :(')
        #print (self.win)          


    def grid(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.place = int(self.place)
        self.place -= 1
        lst = self.grd_lst
        lst[self.place] = x

        #print ('\n')
        for x in reversed(range(0,8,3)):
            print (lst[x],'|',lst[x+1],'|',lst[x+2])
        print ('\n')

    def loop(self):

        while self.plyr_win == False and self.comp_win == False and self.draw != 9:
            self.plyr_chs()
            self.check()
            self.winner(1)
            time.sleep(1)
            self.grid('x')
            time.sleep(2)
            self.draw += 1
            if self.plyr_win == False and self.comp_win == False and self.draw != 9:
                self.comp_chs()
                time.sleep(2)
                self.check()
                self.winner(-1)
                self.grid('o')
                time.sleep(2)
                self.draw += 1
            else:
                print ("It's a draw")





print ("Welcome!!! Let's play a game of tic tac toe!!")
time.sleep(2)
print ("You will be 'x'")
time.sleep(2)
print ("Choose where you want 'x' to go")
time.sleep(2)
print ("Here are your choices.") 
time.sleep(2)
print (" 7 | 8 | 9\n 4 | 5 | 6\n 1 | 2 | 3\n")
time.sleep(4)
print ("Type the number you want 'x' to replace")
ttt = TicTacToe()
ttt.loop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use abbreviations in your code.

- `grd_lst` is hard to understand. The `i` key on your keyboard seems to work (at least you could `import time`), so you should name it `grid_list` instead. Otherwise your readers will wonder what you meant with `greedy_lost` or `guard_last`.
- Same for `plyr_chs`. Vowels are nice people, you should not ban them from your code. Abbreviations will only distract readers. Did you know that in the 1980s and 1990s, hard disk sizes were measured by their `chs` values (cylinders, heads, sectors)?

Line 48: `self.place == ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']` will never be `True` since the human and the computer only ever enter a single number. And that cannot be *the same* as the list. You should change the `==` into `in`.

There's no point in calling `time.sleep`. Why should the computer pause *before* giving an error message? This would look as if it were a difficult decision, which it isn't.

The code for the `winner` function is very long. Many other people have written the code similar like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.board = [' ' for i in range(10)]   # entry 0 is unused

def play(self, pos):
    self.board[pos] = self.turn
    self.turn = 'X' if self.turn == 'O' else 'O'

def triplet(self, a, b, c):
    board = self.board
    turn = self.turn
    return board[a] == turn and board[b] == turn and board[c] == turn

def won(self):
    return self.triplet(7, 8, 9) or
           self.triplet(4, 5, 6) or
           self.triplet(1, 2, 3) or
           self.triplet(1, 4, 7) or
           self.triplet(2, 5, 8) or
           self.triplet(3, 6, 9) or
           self.triplet(1, 5, 9) or
           self.triplet(3, 5, 7)
```

The idea of using the keypad on the keyboard for numbering the 9 cells is great. All other tic-tac-toe programs I have seen until now have the `1 2 3` in the top row, which requires more thought from the human player than necessary.